# Selenium how to extract href from attributes

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="turbolink_scroller" id="container">
 <article><div class="inner- article">
  <a style="height:81px;" href="LINK TO EXTRACT">
   <img width="81" height="81" src="//image.jpg" alt="code" />
```

Hello! I'm pretty new to selenium and I've been playing around with how to get sources for my webdriver. So far, I'm trying to extract a href link given an alt code as above and I'm not sure if the documentation has a means to do this. I'm feeling that the answer is find_by_xpath but I'm not entirely sure. Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way is as follows

```
href = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
```

of course, you may have a lot of 'a' tags in a page, so you may make the path to your respective tag,

e.g

```
div = driver.find_element_by_id('container')
a = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
href = a.get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: But suppose I have "code" in the alt tag, how would I be able to find_element_by_tag_name if it is not explicitly a tag?

Comment: "code" is still a tag, you should be able to find it by tag, in the odd case where selenium don't want to do it you can use css selector, or class name if it has a class or id if it has an id.

Comment: lets say, your tag is named, qwerty

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('qwerty') <- this will return an array so you just specify the one that you are looking for with the index and then do get_attribute(), it supports custom attributes as well

Comment: Yes, exactly. as long as 'code' is the one that has the href

Comment: Good Answer @ShailynOrtiz +1